# PHP MySQL Database auto increment Based on amount of rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am looking for a table field that has a numeric value based the number of rows in the table, and also number it by the title in ASC.

Is there anything like this?

Any Help Greatly Apreciated

**UPDATE**

Its seems that this is a bad idea... Is there any way in php to count all the rows and find a rows number by id and have all the rows ordered by ASC?

Comment: set the column to int with auto increment, is that what you need?

Comment: but then if i delete a record it wont renumber everything will it? There will most probably be a gap, like i have 1,2,3,4,5 and i delete 3 it will result in 1,2,4,5 and i need it to result in 1,2,3,4

Comment: well yes the content of that col, wont change, You can do a trigger that runs on insert/update to update a specific column for you

Comment: No. Renumbering is usually not necessary.

Comment: Would it be efficient to re-update every row in the database every time an item is removed?

Comment: @Dawid van der Hoven it depends, for few hundreds of updates you won't notice any performance issues. but if its thousands or millions then for sure

Comment: What? It would be disastrous! Gaps are good. Celebrate the gap. You do not need to (and should not) store this 'row number' in the database. Just calculate it on-the-fly as and when required. Frankly I can't believe that other correspondents are suggesting otherwise.

Comment: @Strawberry Exactly what i discovered, could you possibly give me an example at how i calculate something like that in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the OP's request for some generic solutions...

Consider the following...

```
 SELECT recipe FROM recipes ORDER BY recipe;
 +---------------------------------+
 | recipe                          |
 +---------------------------------+
 | Beans & Macaroni                |
 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |
 | Beans on Toast                  |
 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |
 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |
 | Cheese on Toast                 |
 | Macaroni & Cheese               |
 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |
 | Toast & Jam                     |
 +---------------------------------+

 MySQL Method 1.
 SET @i = 0;

 SELECT @i:=@i+1 rank, recipe FROM recipes ORDER BY recipe;
 +------+---------------------------------+
 | rank | recipe                          |
 +------+---------------------------------+
 |    1 | Beans & Macaroni                |
 |    2 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |
 |    3 | Beans on Toast                  |
 |    4 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |
 |    5 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |
 |    6 | Cheese on Toast                 |
 |    7 | Macaroni & Cheese               |
 |    8 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |
 |    9 | Toast & Jam                     |
 +------+---------------------------------+

 MySQL Method 2.
 SELECT COUNT(*) rank, x.recipe FROM recipes x JOIN recipes y ON y.recipe <= x.recipe GROUP BY x.recipe ORDER BY rank;
 +------+---------------------------------+
 | rank | recipe                          |
 +------+---------------------------------+
 |    1 | Beans & Macaroni                |
 |    2 | Beans on Jacket Potato          |
 |    3 | Beans on Toast                  |
 |    4 | Cheese & Beans on Jacket Potato |
 |    5 | Cheese & Beans on Toast         |
 |    6 | Cheese on Toast                 |
 |    7 | Macaroni & Cheese               |
 |    8 | Peanut Butter on Toast          |
 |    9 | Toast & Jam                     |
 +------+---------------------------------+

 PHP Method
 <?php
 include('../testi.inc');
 $query = "SELECT recipe FROM recipes ORDER BY recipe;
 ;";

 $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
 $x='';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $x[] = $row['recipe'];
 }


 ?>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <?
  for($i=0;$i<count($x);$i++){
  $j = $i+1;
  echo $j."</td><td>".$x[$i]."</td></tr>\n<tr><td>";
  }
  ?>
  </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

trigger an event whenever your table row is deleted just re order it by incrementing the custom row id in all rows..

Comment: When I posted my answer, It was not there..  There were only first 2 comments available...

Answer (score 0):

As other already stated, this is the wrong approach, but in case you need renumbering (it's valid for sort column for example), here is the query:

```
UPDATE 
    tabaleName 
SET 
    fieldName = fieldName - 1 
WHERE 
    fieldName > 5 
ORDER BY 
   fieldName 
ASC
```

And since you are using auto-increment, you have to reset it

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=10000
```

But please, note, I post this for education purposes only. This is the wrong approach!

Comment: why u want to re-numbering row

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need is a time-specific numbering of rows at the time of your queries. Other databases solve this through methods like ROWID (oracle) or ROW_NUMBER (T-SQL, MS-SQL-Server), where you can generate a column with a row number for a current record set like this:

SELECT column1, column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (column3, column4) as rownumber

This will generate a row number while respecting deleted rows. Sadly, MySQL doesn't support such function.

You can emulate the behaviour with a variable, incrementing for each record found. See a possible solution using CROSS JOIN on mysql.number [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/). I'd be interested in the performance (or an EXPLAIN EXTENDED) of such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a view of the table. I occasionally have need of a select query that produces rows already numbered, and it is easy enough to do this with a variable.

Something like this:

```
SELECT @count:=@count+1, t.* FROM (SELECT * FROM <your-table>) t, (SELECT @count:=0) z;
```